Polar Set of a Polyhedra is a Polytope
I am having trouble to verify Proposition 2 from the following MIT OCW document:

Is there a way for us to see the equivalence of $C_1$ and $C_2$ simply through the definition? I do notice there was a proof (Equivalence of two definitions of polar of polytope) using the LP duality theorem, but I hope to see a more elementary proof, as it seems to be claimed by the document.
The document: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-409-topics-in-theoretical-computer-science-an-algorithmists-toolkit-fall-2009/de0c446f55600a66c250ad6d7be77375_MIT18_409F09_scribe11.pdf

Is that claim true? If $C = {x: \ x\le 2, \ -x \le 2}$ then $C=[-2,2]$ and $C^*=[-1/2,+1/2] \ne conv(a_1,a_2) = [-1,+1]$.

These kind of claims of equality of two convex sets are usually of the following type: one direction/inclusions is trivial, the other inclusion needs a separation/duality argument to prove it.

@daw It seems like this might not be true.. Perhaps the correct version of the statement should be something like $C_1 = \mathrm{conv}(a_1/b_1, \cdots, a_k/b_k)$ assuming $b_i > 0$? Or just normalizing $b_i$'s to $1$, should fix this problem?

Yes, this might work. In the  question you have linked, the $b_i$'s are euqal to one.
